# Different Java versions applications is not working in Tomcat 6 server

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

We have two Struts 2 web applications with different Java environments. One is Java 1.5 and another one is Java 1.6.

These two applications must be run in my production server (Linux environment) the versions there are Java 1.6 and Tomcat 6.

I get the exception in my production server like:

```
[ INFO] 2011-04-15 12:59:00,221 [BasicTilesContainer] (BasicTilesContainer.java:init:116)
Initializing Tiles2 container. . .

[ INFO] 2011-04-15 12:59:00,240 [BasicTilesContainer] (BasicTilesContainer.java:initializeDefinitionsFactory:204)
Tiles2 container initialization complete.

[ INFO] 2011-04-15 12:59:00,241 [TilesAccess] (TilesAccess.java:setContainer:95)
Publishing TilesContext for context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade

Apr 15, 2011 12:59:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Apr 15, 2011 12:59:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/test] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: You've asked 12 questions and accepted no answers. I'm not sure anyone here can help.

Comment: @Brian @Tommi I said the same thing while answering one of his questions, and its still zero.

Comment: <rant removed> Still, the question is a bit vague. My understanding is that 1.5 application fails to deploy to 1.6-running server? This version incompatibility happens, and developers should take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you talk to the developers of the application that is failing and ask them about this, or at least ask them how to enable better error reporting.